# Javascript Change Multiple Divs Content Based on Selection

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a dropdown selection with various options and multiple divs that should change content according to the selected option like so (dropdown option in bold):

**House #1**
House Color #1
House Location #1
House Size #1

**House #2**
House Color #2
House Location #2
House Size #2

Most solutions use a **show/hide script** but that **wouldn't work** for me because I would end up with too many hidden duplicate divs for every color, location, size, etc..

I would love to have options with values:

```
<select>
<option value="house 1">House #1</option>
<option value="house 2">House #2</option>
<option value="house 3">House #3</option>
</select>
```

and use IDs for divs like

```
<div id="color">House Color #1</div>
<div id="location">House Location #1</div>
<div id="size">House Size #1</div>
```

and have all the corresponding values somewhere in a separate js script in the background where the logic is

div id='color' is (house 1 = House Color #1), (house 2 = House Color #2) etc..

div id='size' is (house 1 = House Size #1), (house 2 = House Size #2) etc..

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: id's have to be unique. Use either data attributes or classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the select's `onchange`-event to pass the current house-value to a function that retrieves the corresponding values and updates your page by setting the `innerHTML`-attribute of your respective divs.

```js
const data = {
  "house 1":{
    color:"yes",
    location:"Mars",
    size:"small",
  },
  "house 2":{
    color:"all",
    location:"Neverland",
    size:"rather huge",
  },
  "house 3":{
    color:"mauve",
    location:"Los Angeles",
    size:"It's ok",
  },
};

function showHouse(value) {
  document.getElementById("color").innerHTML=data[value]["color"];
  document.getElementById("location").innerHTML=data[value]["location"];
  document.getElementById("size").innerHTML=data[value]["size"];
}
showHouse("house 1");
document.querySelector("select").onchange=e=>showHouse(e.target.value);
```

```html
<select>
<option value="house 1">House #1</option>
<option value="house 2">House #2</option>
<option value="house 3">House #3</option>
</select>

<div id="color">House Color #1</div>
<div id="location">House Location #1</div>
<div id="size">House Size #1</div>
```

---

**Bonus:** If you plan on having many more fields you can shorten the code like this:

```
["color","location","size","altitude"].forEach(
    a=>document.getElementById(a).innerHTML=data[value][a]
);
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I needed :) I would upvote it but my rep won't let me.

Comment: I actually have multiple dropdown selects on a page, and when I duplicate your code for the other dropdown, it stops working.. Of course I set unique data, showHouse, and IDs. But it's not woking. Any tip on how to make this work for mutliple dropdowns on a single page? Thank you!

Comment: Maybe because of `document.querySelector("select")`.. Have you given each select an id? Then replace it with `document.getElementById("selectID")`

Comment: Sorry, I actually figured it out and came back here and saw your comment. Yes it was the select ID. Now it works perfectly. Thanks again buddy!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by this way...

```js
$("#house").change(function(){
 var house = $("#house").val();
 $("#selectedHouse").html('<b>House #'+house+'</b>');
 $("#color").html('House Color #'+house);
 $("#location").html('House Location #'+house);
 $("#size").html('House Size #'+house);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="house" name="house">
<option value="1">House #1</option>
<option value="2">House #2</option>
<option value="3">House #3</option>
</select>

<div id="selectedHouse"><b>House #1</b></div>
<div id="color">House Color #1</div>
<div id="location">House Location #1</div>
<div id="size">House Size #1</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give id to your dropdown and on change of it's value call this update function passing the dropdown selection

```
<select id=house onChange= update(this)>
<option value="house 1">House #1</option>
<option value="house 2">House #2</option>
<option value="house 3">House #3</option>
</select>
```

you can have a function which retrives the color,location,and size based on your house selection. Am assuming color,location and size divisions to be textboxes. Modify the function based on your div elements

```
  function update(house){
        var color = document.getElementById("color");
        color.value = getColor(house);// you can call the js file which returns color based on house
var size = document.getElementById("size");
        size.value = getColor(house);// you can call the js file which returns size based on house
var location = document.getElementById("size");
        location.value = getColor(house);// you can call the js file which returns location based on house
        var selection = dropdown.value;
        console.log(selection);
        var emailTextBox = document.getElementById("email");
        // assign the email address here based on your need.

      }
```